Inner product on a symmetric sum of tensor products
I have a space $V$ of $6 \times 6$ matrices whose basis is $\{1,S,M\}$; writing the components indices: $\{1_{ij},S_{ij},M_{ij}\}$ where $i,j=1,\cdots, 6$. The inner product on this space is
\begin{equation}
\langle A, B\rangle_{V} := \text{Tr} [ A^{\dagger}B  ]
=\sum_{i,j}(A^{\dagger})_{ij}(B)_{ji}
\equiv
(A^{\dagger})_{ij}(B)_{ji}.
\end{equation}
Besides, the tensor product space $V \otimes V$ has the basis $\{1\otimes 1, 1 \otimes S, \cdots, M \otimes M \}$; writing the components indices: $\{(1\otimes 1)_{ijmn} = 1_{ij}1_{mn},(1\otimes S)_{ijmn} =1_{ij}S_{mn},\cdots, (M\otimes M)_{ijmn} =M_{ij}M_{mn}\}$, and it's possible to define an inner product on this tensor product space as
\begin{equation}
\langle A \otimes B, C \otimes D \rangle_{V\otimes V}
:=
\langle A,C \rangle_{V}
\langle B,D \rangle_{V}
=
\text{Tr}[A^{\dagger}C]
\text{Tr}[B^{\dagger}D]
=
(A^{\dagger})_{ij}
(C)_{ji}
(B^{\dagger})_{mn}
(D)_{nm}.
\end{equation}
Now, doing some physics calculations in QFT, I have found a kind of new space, let's call it $W$, whose basis seems to be
\begin{align}
\mathcal{B}_{W}=&\{\mathbf{1}_{ijmn}=(1\otimes 1)_{ijmn}+(1\otimes 1)_{inmj} , \mathbf{S}_{ijmn}=(S\otimes S)_{ijmn}+(S\otimes S)_{inmj}, \mathbf{M}_{ijmn}=(M\otimes M)_{ijmn}+(M\otimes M)_{inmj}  \}
\\
=&
\{\mathbf{1}_{ijmn}=1_{ij}1_{mn}+1_{in}1_{mj} , \mathbf{S}_{ijmn}=S_{ij}S_{mn}+S_{in}S_{mj}, \mathbf{M}_{ijmn}=M_{ij}M_{mn}+M_{in}M_{mj}  \}.
\end{align}
Observations:

The elements of this basis are made of two terms. Each term is a tensor product, but the second term has a pair of indices exchanged with respect to the first $j \leftrightarrow n$.

All the elements of the basis are of the form $\mathbf{X}_{ijmn}= (X\otimes X)_{ijmn}+(X\otimes X)_{inmj} = X_{ij}X_{mn}+X_{in}X_{mj}$; there are no cross terms like $(\mathbf{XY})_{ijmn}= (X\otimes Y)_{ijmn}+(X\otimes Y)_{inmj} = X_{ij}Y_{mn}+X_{in}Y_{mj}$

All the elements have the symmetry $\mathbf{A}_{ijmn}=\mathbf{A}_{mjin}=\mathbf{A}_{inmj}$.

This space seems to be a kind of symmetric (direct?) sum of two copies of $V \otimes V$, where the second copy has the indices $j \leftrightarrow n$ exchanged with respect the first copy.


My main question is:

Is it possible to define an inner product on $W$? If so, how is it defined?

Any reference, idea or suggestion is welcome. By the way: I'm physicist (not mathematician), sorry for my ignorance.

You should focus your question to one question only. As it is right now, your question is against math stackexchange guidelines.

@Tina I've changed it, please check it and tell me if it's right this way

You should delete the other two questions, then its a good question. But feel free to ask the other two question as new questions!

"Is it possible" Yes, and very uninteresting. You can define an inner product on any vector space. In fact, choosing a basis always gives you a canonical inner product. To make it interesting, you need to specify what properties you want this inner product to have.

Writing $V=A\otimes B^*$ your last construct is the invariant set (or eigenspace of the eigenvalue 1) of the (order 2) map $V\otimes V\to V\otimes V$ generated by $a\otimes b\otimes c\otimes d\mapsto a\otimes d\otimes c\otimes b$. A scalar product for this subspace need not care about positive definiteness outside the subspace, so there is some more design freedom. What to select among the many possibilities depends on the desired applications.
